# ORDER BY in statement before UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar) AS ID,
    CONCAT([SIF_DRZAVE].NAZIV_DRZAVE,' - ',CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar),' - Zona I')  AS NAZIV
FROM 
    [dbo].[SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [SIF_DRZAVE] ON ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE]=[SIF_DRZAVE].[ID_DRZAVE]) 
WHERE 
    [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].SIF_VRSTA_USLUGA = 139 
    AND ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 295 
         OR [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 293)

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar) AS ID,
    CONCAT([SIF_DRZAVE].NAZIV_DRZAVE,' - ',CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar),' - Zona II') AS NAZIV 
FROM 
    [dbo].[SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [SIF_DRZAVE] ON ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE]=[SIF_DRZAVE].[ID_DRZAVE]) 
WHERE 
    [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].SIF_VRSTA_USLUGA = 139 
    AND NOT ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 295 
             OR [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 293)
ORDER BY 
    NAZIV
```

This query orders by 'NAZIV' whole statement after union all.

But i want both query to order by 'NAZIV' before UNION ALL

Comment: Then put each query in `(...)` with an `order by` in each one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @juergen d: No. If you want a query ordered you must place an `ORDER BY` at the end. If you union all two separate sorted queries, the DBMS is free to ouput the results in any order.

Comment: @juergend I tried that and i have an error , order by clause is invalid in views, inline functions,derived table,subqueries...

Comment: As Gordon pointed out in his answer you don't need `UNION ALL` here. If you did, you would select a constant and use this: `SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS sortkey, ... UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT 2 AS sortkey, ... ORDER BY sortkey, naziv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has numerous issues.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT distinct Cast(ud.[ID_DRZAVE] as varchar(255)) as ID,
       CONCAT(d.NAZIV_DRZAVE, ' - ',
              Cast(ud.[ID_DRZAVE] as varchar(255)),
              (CASE WHEN ud.ID_DRZAVE IN (295, 293) THEN ' - Zona I' ELSE ' - Zona II' END)
             ) as NAZIV
FROM [dbo].[SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA] ud JOIN
     [SIF_DRZAVE] d 
     ON ud.[ID_DRZAVE] = d.[ID_DRZAVE]
WHERE d.SIF_VRSTA_USLUGA = 139 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ud.ID_DRZAVE IN (295, 293) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         NAZIV;
```

Notes:

- The `FULL JOIN`s are being undone by the `WHERE` clause.  Use the appropriate `JOIN`.
- Use `IN` rather than chained `OR` conditions.
- Never use `VARCHAR()` with no length in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and debugging this problem can be really challenging.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You don't need a `UNION`/`UNION ALL` at all for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I think i must use union , cause i need to get list witch will concatenate string "- Zona I" to countries with id  in (295,293) and concatenate string" - Zona II " if countries have id other then 295,293

Comment: @DusanRadosavljevic . . . I adapted the answer.  That difference wasn't obvious in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column so you can get the order you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    '1' AS ZONA,
    CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar) AS ID,
    CONCAT([SIF_DRZAVE].NAZIV_DRZAVE,' - ',CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar),' - Zona I')  AS NAZIV
FROM 
    [dbo].[SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [SIF_DRZAVE] ON ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE]=[SIF_DRZAVE].[ID_DRZAVE]) 
WHERE 
    [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].SIF_VRSTA_USLUGA = 139 
    AND ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 295 
        OR [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 293)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
    '2',
    CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar) AS ID,
    CONCAT([SIF_DRZAVE].NAZIV_DRZAVE,' - ',CAST([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE] AS varchar),' - Zona II') AS NAZIV 
FROM 
    [dbo].[SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [SIF_DRZAVE] ON ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].[ID_DRZAVE]=[SIF_DRZAVE].[ID_DRZAVE]) 
WHERE 
    [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].SIF_VRSTA_USLUGA = 139 
    AND NOT ([SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 295 
         OR [SV_USLUGA_DRZAVA].ID_DRZAVE = 293)
ORDER BY 
    ZONA, NAZIV
```